# Usage of "by which"

Tags: clauses, relative-pronouns

I want to explain a technical idea - see below sentence.

> After collecting the candidates and prioritizing them using one of
>   the above methods, the sorted candidates are stored as a list of line
>   numbers **by which,** the list give a similar neighbourhood list as
>   given by the r-tree (random tree) data structure.

If I say my idea briefly in another way:

> by doing it that way (the way I explained above), I can get a list which is very similar to that obtained by following r-tree (another method).

My question is, if I use **by which**, does this clearly describe my original idea?

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand the first paragraph in quote :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*by which* is legitmate phrase to use for expressing clarification, but, in your sentence, there should be no comma after it.

> After collecting the candidates and prioritizing them using one of the above methods, the sorted candidates are stored as a list of line numbers by which the list give* a similar neighbourhood list as given by the r-tree (random tree) data structure.

That's long and hard to follow. I think it would be better to simply replace the *by which* with a full stop:

> After collecting the candidates and prioritizing them using one of the above methods, the sorted candidates are stored as a list of line numbers. This list give* a neighborhood list similar to the one given by the r-tree structure.

One other suggestion: consider picking a different verb than *give*. I won't tell you which one (you're the domain expert), but you might try looking up synonyms for *provide, construct,* or *return*.

---

*denotes a verb that might be conjugated wrong.